# cPanel MySQL upgrade fail CentOS

Tags: mysql, cpanel, whm

I have recently purchase a VPS, however the same was with old version of cPanel. I have run an upgrade of the cPanel to the latest version. However after the upgrade I am unable to upgrade the MySQL service to 5.6:

When I try to upgrade the MySQL service to 5.5 I am able to see next message in the WHM browser console:

[2016-12-23 13:41:40 +0000] file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz from install of MySQL55-devel-5.5.52-1.cp1156.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-devel-5.5.53-1.el6.x86_64
[2016-12-23 13:41:40 +0000] W Error Code: 8
[2016-12-23 13:41:40 +0000] Hooks system enabled.
[2016-12-23 13:41:40 +0000] Checking for and running RPM::Versions 'post' hooks for any RPMs about to be installed
[2016-12-23 13:41:40 +0000] All required 'post' hooks have been run
[2016-12-23 13:41:40 +0000] Restoring service monitoring.
Restarting mysql service.
Waiting for “mysql” to restart ……waiting for “mysql” to initialize ………finished.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you guys! :)

Comment: MariaDB is already installed by the looks of it, it's conflicting with that. Not sure if you can actually run both on the same machine or not (they're almost the same product, forked). Was MySQL actually installed already, or are you doing a fresh install? But if you can then perhaps they both have to be at the same point release - the conflict you've got is between very slightly different version numbers. I'd try installing exactly the same version (if it exists) and see if that helps.

Comment: P.S. I'm not a sysadmin really, just got a tiny bit of Linux experience. You might get more help on http://serverfault.com/ - SO is mainly for coding problems, not system config.

Comment: As long as you have MariaDB installed you won't be able to upgrade to MySQL 5.6.x. By default cPanel/WHM comes with MySQL 5.5.x. You have the option to upgrade to MySQL 5.6.x or to MariaDB 10.x (recommended by cPanel) or alternatively to MariaDB 10.1.x. As it's stated in WHM on the MySQL Upgrade interface, the process is ireversible. If you did upgrade the default MySQL version to MariaDB, you won't be able to swtitch from MariaDB to MySQL 5.6.x. There is possible to do it but it won't work on the fly using the WHM interface. You have to do it via SSH and it's not that easy. Hope it helps!